# how to convert osm file to osm.pbf using c# code

Tags: c#, .net, openstreetmap

I want convert osm file to osm.pbf file using c#. as i tried by using osmsharp library but not i think it is not working properly (may be not coming with compressed way also).so please help to find out and i also need this without using any third party application like JOSM.

This is what i tried.it is also not coming with compressed even if i send the  "compress = true" it is giving some error.

```
string InputFile = @"D:\JOSM\JOSMFolder\OSM.osm";
string Outputfile = @"D:\JOSM\JOSMFolder\OSM.osm.pbf";

using (var xmlStream = new FileInfo(InputFile).OpenRead())
{
    XmlOsmStreamSource source = new XmlOsmStreamSource(xmlStream);

    // Write OSM data to the PBF file.
    using (var pbfStream = new FileInfo(Outputfile).OpenWrite())
    {
        //bool compress = true;
        PBFOsmStreamTarget target = new PBFOsmStreamTarget(pbfStream);
        target.Initialize();
        target.RegisterSource(source);
        target.Pull();
    }
}
```